# VBA code creating false.xml files

Tags: excel, vba

I use the code below to save a workbook using two fields as the name.  This part works dead on but when the save as window opens and i click cancel, it creates a false.xml excel file.  Not sure as to why.  I have tried using without the if statement but still creates it.

Can someone tell me why this happens and how to stop it?

Also is there code to catch errors in vb?

Regards

```
Sub FileSave()

Dim IntialName As String
Dim fileSaveName As Variant

InitialName = Range("C2") & " " & Range("H2") & " Cash Sheet"
fileSaveName = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(InitialFileName:=InitialName, _
fileFilter:="Excel Files (*.xls), *.xls")

If fileSaveName <> False Then
MsgBox "Save as " & fileSaveName
End If

ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs fileSaveName

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code you check for `If fileSaveName <> False` but if it is false you save the workbook in spite. So VBA builds an filename from this `False` value. Write

```
If fileSaveName <> False Then
  MsgBox "Save as " & fileSaveName
  ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs fileSaveName
End If
```

instead.

For error handling in VBA look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5hsw66as.aspx).

Comment: Legend, Ill get the handle on this VBA yet.. appreciate it